# pcap file 20 times smaller than ifconfig TX/RX difference for same period

Tags: linux, openwrt, tcpdump, modem

I run tcpdump on a usb modem in network card mode.

```
[   18.260000] cdc_ncm 1-1.1:1.1 wwan0: register 'cdc_ncm' at usb-ehci-platform-1.1, Mobile Broadband Network Device, 0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64
```

I run it for several minutes and also run ifconfig before and after to see the counters difference.

```
{
    sh -c '
    fn1() {
        date
        echo $1
        ifconfig wwan0
        echo
    } >&2
    fn1 before
    tcpdump -i wwan0 -w - &
    sleep 600
    kill $!
    wait
    fn1 after
    ' >day3.pcap
} 2>&1 | tee day3.txt
```

Result:

```
Sun Jul 26 13:37:32 AST 2015
before
...
          RX packets:45568603 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:42531282 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1843669466 (1.7 GiB)  TX bytes:2947749207 (2.7 GiB)


tcpdump: listening on wwan0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
44788 packets captured
44802 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
Sun Jul 26 13:47:32 AST 2015
after
...
          RX packets:45585747 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:42558941 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1845868782 (1.7 GiB)  TX bytes:3158560778 (2.9 GiB)
```

- packets: 42558941 + 45585747 - 42531282 - 45568603 = 44803
- bytes: 1845868782 + 3158560778 - 1843669466 - 2947749207 = 213 010 887

As you can see the packets number is almost the same.

day3.pcap is only 12Mb in size

```
$ tshark -r day3.pcap -z io,stat,0,"SUM(frame.len)frame.len" | tail -5
|                |1         |     |
| Interval       |    SUM   |     |
|---------------------------|     |
|   0.0 <> 599.6 | 12087649 |     |
===================================
```

Why does ifconfig show a difference of 200Mb? 213010887 / 44803 = 4754. What? MTU is only 1500

Answer (score 0):

Some older versions of tcpdump truncate packets that they capture, [here's a bit of information on that](http://www.alexonlinux.com/tcpdump-for-dummies#changing_packet_size_in_the_capture_file). That would cause it to store less data than was received on the interface.

Based on the packet counts in both, I'm assuming it was not a firewall or promiscuous mode switch error, some interfaces refuse to go into promiscuous mode and drop traffic bound for other MAC addresses.

Comment: The wwan hardware and information on the tcpdump, libpcap & os version would help answer the question more fully.

Comment: "capture size 65535 bytes" indicates that this version of tcpdump defaults to a large snapshot size of 65535, rather than the smaller default snapshot sizes of 68 or 96 bytes to which you're referring, so that's probably not the issue.